# Kivy - Update Canvas background with value passed from Python

Tags: python, canvas, background, kivy

Struggling to update the image source of a canvas from the python:

This is the .KV section:

```
BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    padding: "5dp"
                    size_hint_y: 0.70                   
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgb: .6, .6, .6 
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                            source: "image.png"
```

On the python side I have a function returning the new image name which I would like to pass to source in order to update "image.png" to "image2.png"

I tried to add an ID within the .kv but unfortunately it does not work for the "Rectangle"

Any wonderful ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are accessible perfectly fine from outside with e.g builtin names (`app` for App instance, `root` for main rule/class, `self` for current widget's instance). Ids will not work because `canvas` (before, classic, after) is constructed **before** anything else is, therefore you won't be able to access `ids` in a canvas of a widget you build the canvas for.

After the canvas is constructed, then such things as ids work in the way you expect them to work.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    variable: 'blob'
    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            source: app.test  # self.variable
'''


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.test = 'path'
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```